# Using 'override' keyword

Tags: oop, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism

My code gives the following error:

> error C3668: 'B::getData': method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods

```
#include<iostream>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    int a;

    int getData() {
        return a;
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:
    int b;
    B() {
        b = 100;
    }

    int getData() override {
        return b;
    }
};

int main() {
    B b;
    cout << b.getData() << endl;
}
```

Why does error occurs and how can I resolve it ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original function in `A` has to be `virtual` to be `override`d.

```
class A {
public:
    int a;

    virtual int getData() {
        return a;
    }
};
```

More info about `override` is [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override). And related: [info on `virtual`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) and [`final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)